# HP thin client T610 freeRDP old authentication

Tags: client, thin

We are using HP Thin Clients type F5A52AA#UUZ (Linux HPThinPro) to connect to a Windows 2016 Terminal Server.
Connection works - but in our environment we use the old RDP authentication (we now the possible DoS problem based on such a configuration) and based on that we don't need the supported pro login of freeRDP.
Is there a simple configuration to hide/turn off the pre login provided by freeRDP?

Sugestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using custom connection with command line:

xfreerdp -authentication:off /:IPAddress ...

Comment: xfreerdp -authentication:off /v:IPAddress